# Possible bug in SQL Server 2019, any solutions?

Tags: indexing, parallel-processing, duplicates, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

We did an in place upgrade on one of our lower environment servers from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2019. We have two databases on that server. We put both databases in compatibility level 150. We have a stored procedure that joins Table A to Table B in database A to database B.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
    SELECT A.ColumnA, A.ColumnB, B.ColumnB
    FROM TableA A 
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ColumnD = B.ColumnD
    WHERE A.ColumnE = 2
```

When this was ran in SQL Server 2016, it inserted a unique list of data into TableA. Since upgrading to SQL Server 2019, it is duplicating some rows up to 60 times in one run. If I back the compatibility level down to 130, it goes back to being a unique list.

This only happens when the indexes are disabled. If I enable the indexes, it does not happen or if I make the `SELECT` perform under MAXDOP 1.

Any ideas? Why would it work so differently? If I were to take the data that would be inserted and look at it, as shown below, it that query only returns one record.

```
SELECT A.ColumnA, A.ColumnB, B.ColumnB
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ColumnD = B.ColumnD
WHERE A.ColumnE = 2 
  AND A.ColumnA = 2342342 
  AND B.ColumnB = 9228382
```

Is this a bug? I've tried all the CU's to see if it's been fixed or if it was introduced by one of them. Nothing works.

**Answers to a couple of the questions that I have been asked.**

1. Yes, this is reproduceable, even by creating a new tables in new databases and copying the data to the new tables before running the INSERT.
2. I've completely dropped and recreated the indexes.
3. I've completely dropped all stats and let them rebuild naturally
4. I am not using NOLOCK
5. Process runs in 5 minutes with indexes disabled, takes 30 minutes when they are enabled. Rebuild of indexes takes less than a minute. If I drop the indexes and put them back at the end, the build of the indexes takes 20 minutes. This is why we are just disabling them. Has always worked in the past, never an issue.
6. I would love to post the execution plan, will try and get that done on Monday. Unfortunately, the server is going to be busy that day and I may not be able to get that done. I did take a casual glance at the execution plans for 130 and 150 and they looked identical, but I did not do a thorough examination.
7. The indexes are definitely needed for other processes that occur on these tables, can't just remove them.

UPDATE:

I have a case open with Microsoft.

Comment: Does it also return unexpected rows run as a select or only when inserting? Does the execution plan also show the diplicate rows? Can you reproduce it? Have you tried the insert/select the opposite way round between servers? Have you rebuilt indexes/refreshed stats? Sounds like you might want to open a case with Microsoft, if it's truly a bug you will get a hotfix (hopefully) and won't be charged.

Comment: Upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: Do your actual queries use `NOLOCK`? The fact that you only see the symptom under parallelism makes me skeptical. How much time are you saving by disabling the indexes? Don't you have to just rebuild them right after anyway? Or maybe they aren't needed at all? Are any of them both unique and covering?

Comment: @TheSQLGuy any word back on the case?

Comment: Yes,  MS confirmed that it was a bug and they fixed it after I reported it.  Fix is in SQL 2019 CU23.  Look up the Halloween bug for more information about this bug.  MS has fixed it several times, keeps coming back.